# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on an observable and am getting this error "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures. This is the method that gets called:

```
accountTypeAhead(param, url = this.accountAutoComplete): Observable <any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('prefix', param);
    return this.http.get(url, {params: params}).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

and then I am getting the error here in my component:

```
dataSource: Observable<any>;
this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    this.users.accountAutoComplete(this.userForm.value.prefix).subscribe((result: any) => {
        observer.next(result.payload);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you remove the `.json()` from the `map`, does that change/help anything? You are using the HttpClient, right?

Comment: yes i am using http client

Comment: i removed he .map and still getting a type error. I swear I have been stuck on a stupid typeahead for two days now!

Comment: Sorry you are frustrated. What is the likelihood of you putting this into a StackBlitz so we can try some things?

Comment: yea it may take me a bit, but I will get something up

Comment: @R.Richards https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynjt4f?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: You are calling `this.users.accountAutoComplete` like it is a function, when it is only a string variable in the service.  Did you really want to call the `this.users.accountTypeAhead` function instead?

Comment: yes i need to call it as a function

Comment: You can't call `accountAutoComplete` like a function, it isn't a function, it's just a string. You CAN call `accountTypeAhead`; that IS a function. `accountAutoComplete` != `accountTypeAhead(...)`

Comment: FFS!!!!! Thank you SOOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: LOL! Maybe you should walk away from this one for a little while. :)